# App crashes on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: objective-c, localnotification

My app has a local notification that works well when the app is open or in the background.  However, when I completely close the app and the notification triggers, it is displayed but the app freezes when I click on it.  It does not load a new view.  I'd like the app to just load the standard view that is loaded when the app is first launched.  Therefore, I've declared `#import "ViewController.h"` in app delegate.m.  Then I have the following:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

ViewController *vc;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [_window addSubview:vc.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

However, when I click on the app after the notification tiggers (while the app is closed), the app opens to the last view that was there and then I get a black screen of death.  Any help? I cant figure it out. I've tried so many things.

Comment: What's up with `ViewController *vc;`? What the heck is that supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    ViewController *vc = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    [_window addSubview:vc.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/F89D71D3-1103-4321-BAD1-221003EE70A5/play.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x37c1f8bf 0x3776b1e5 0x37c1f7b9 0x37c1f7db 0x3193b747 0x318ab9cb 0x3178aea1 0x3170078b 0x29d7 0x316ff7eb 0x316f93bd 0x316c7921 0x316c73bf 0x316c6d2d 0x3794ddf3 0x37bf3553 0x37bf34f5 0x37bf2343 0x37b754dd 0x37b753a5 0x316f8457 0x316f5743 0x28e7 0x288c)
terminate called throwing an exception(gdb)

I get that when using the code =(